# If all 3 conditions are true

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, operators

l have an if statement with 3 conditions:

```
if (firstbool == false & Input.GetKeyDown ("space") & secondbool == false) {
        doSomething();
    }
```

l want this program to do something only when all 3 conditions are true. But l don't know which operator l should use.

Comment: && instead of &

Comment: Also, use `!firstBool` instead of `firstBool == false`.

Comment: `if (firstbool && Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && secondbool )`

Comment: @Programmer - you mean `if (!firstbool && Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && !secondbool )` ?

Comment: @Programmer `!important`

Comment: *"do something only when all 3 conditions are true"* Maybe I read that wrong? It didn't say `false`.

Comment: He probably meant that he wanted the state of the bools to be false to be true.

Comment: @Programmer : _do something only when all 3 conditions are true_ I would expect OP is saying (firstbool == false) should be true NOT that firstbool is true, etc

Comment: @DevinLiu and PaulF That make sense. I that case `!` should be added before the two variables.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Using "&&" worked well. And yes, l meant that l wanted the state of the bools to be false to be true. Sorry for my poor English, l couldn't really tell what l meant. :p

Answer (score 1):

You mean to do something like this:

```
if (firstbool == false && Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && secondbool == false)
```

Use the && operator.

Comment: Why does this have two downvotes? It tells the op what they wanted to know, an answer to a bad question sure, but a bad answer...

Comment: Up voted because it answers the question. For some reason it was down voted??

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface I think the down-votes are because this question is really a basic stuff OP should have known or learned somewhere. Also, this answer came after about 30 minutes this question has been answered under the comment section. The people who helped OP through the comment section are not stupid.  Even Bigglesworth's answer, that has been discussed in the comment section. It's just to basic to answer. This is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

To take Devin Liu's answer a bit further you don't need to specify the full syntax of firstbool == false.
If you simply state the bool variable name you are saying it is true or use a ! operator to state the opposite that it is in fact false like so.

```
//for all true
if(firstbool && Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && secondbool)

//or for false bools
if(!firstbool && !Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && !secondbool)
```

Please note however that having the false input would execute over and over while the player is not pressing space which might not be what you want.

Hope it helps